# The usage of Formal Words in writing - interested

Tags: formality, letter-writing

I was writing a letter and I wonder whether the usage of **interested** in a formal letter could be considered as a formal word. Also if there are synonyms which are more appropriate to use in formal letters.

Comment: It depends on what your interest is.  As stated, both the sense of "interested" and your meaning of "formal letter" are too poorly defined to say.

Comment: Note that unless you follow a specific dictionary that indicates *formal* or *informal* in the definition of a word, or a style guide that gives a similar indication, there is no entirely objective way of answering this. Any responses from people saying that *they* think something is formal or not is somewhat subjective. Only if many people say one thing unequivocally would there be some level of indication. Even then, I wouldn't go by a small group of strangers on the internet.

Comment: I've flagged this for closure as "Unclear". Obelisk, please [edit] your post to provide more context for the "usage of **interested**", as there are far too many ways that such a word could be used *appropriately* in a letter, us to be able to answer this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

"Interested" can be used in pretty formal situations and contexts:

> The Czech Republic would be very **interested** in becoming a member of the Special Committee.
>
> Some delegations said that they would be very **interested** in looking further into that proposal.
>
> Another delegate felt that providers of capital would be very **interested** in this type of information.

And it can also be used in rather informal ones:

> I don't think she'd be very **interested** in a guy like me.

All in all, "interested" is a neutral word, and it's often used in formal letters.